# assert that an object is an integer number

Tags: javascript, should.js

Using [should.js](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js), I am currently doing:

```
ordinal.should.be.a.Number().and.equal(Math.floor(ordinal));
```

… is there a more concise way to require that a given object be an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Number.isSafeInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) (to test for 64-bit integers) and [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).  To use with Should.js:

```
should.ok(Number.isSafeInteger(ordinal));
```

I generally recommend using `Number.isSafeInteger`...unless you know you're dealling with potentially really large integer values that have to be stored as floating-point.

Comment: That works. I know it is superfluous but why does `n.should.be.a.Number().and.assert(Number.isSafeInteger(n))` succeeds while `n.should.be.a.Number().and.should.ok(Number.isSafeInteger(n))` fails to complain when 3.2 is given?